# kubeconfig exec - running a binary to get the path for the command

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

I currently have something like this in my kubeconfig

```
 exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1
      command: PATH_DETERMINED_VIA_BINARY/token_generator
      args:
        - --ACCESS_TOKEN
      interactiveMode: Never
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

My question is , in the above the PATH_DETERMINED_VIA_BINARY is obtained by running a binary called `tginfo` like this

```
sudo tginfo path token --> This will return a path (like usr/lib/000012/)
```

Now this is the path that will contain the binary `token_generator` that is used in the command above. My question is how do I call `tginfo` binary to obtain a part of the path that will be used in the command ?

Comment: You can create a shell/python script and execute it using the command argument. In the shell/python script you can declare a variable and store the path in that variable and pass this variable to the token generator command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand the problem is that
you want the output of one command to run as part of another command. In Linux you can use backticks (`) for this. e.g if you want to loop through the item in a particular location. You would do:

```
for i in `ls`;…
```

So in theory something like this will work. The sudo tginfo command is inside backticks so that should get evaluated first followed by its output combined with the rest of the string.

Also look into eval. If this doesn’t work.

```
 exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args:  ["-c", "`sudo tginfo path token`/token_generator --ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      interactiveMode: Never
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

Comment: Can you add some detail as to why this would work?

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: When doing this I get `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field ExecConfig.users.user.exec.command of type string"`

Comment: I think it’s one on the quotes. I just fixed it.